# Linha com imagem no meio

Tags: html, css, imagem, horizontal

Queria estilizar uma `hr` que suportasse uma imagem no meio. 
Tipo:

> ------ imagem ------

Pensei em fazer a imagem já com linha pronta no Photoshop, mas isso dificulta ser responsivo.

É possível estilizar a `hr` para exibir 100% de largura, com a imagem no centro?

Answer (score 4):

O ideal nesse caso é não utilizar a tag `<hr>`, pois como o o que você quer fazer não é a nível de conteúdo e sim visual, o ideal semanticamente falando é você utilizar somente a tag `<img>`.

A solução seria mais ou menos assim.

```css
.imagem-linha {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <img class="imagem-linha" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7a34b7ea8f31265a1da1bb03b8f13bec?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" width="100" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode não precisa fazer uma imagem no photoshop, basta estilizar um `div` para se comportar da forma que deseja, como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.hr-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

.hr-middle::before,
.hr-middle::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  height: 1px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr-middle">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7a34b7ea8f31265a1da1bb03b8f13bec?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" width="50" />
</div>
```

Você pode olhar outras formas de fazer isso [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812770/4843158)

Answer (score 1):

Só com um `hr` não vai conseguir fazer isso.
É preciso usar outros elementos.

Veja neste exemplo que fiz:

```css
#linha {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 100px;
}
hr {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#linha img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 55px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="linha">
    <hr>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7a34b7ea8f31265a1da1bb03b8f13bec?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" width="100" />
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no lugar de adicionar uma imagem apos o hr, você pode adicionar um estilo: `hr:after { content: url('/imagens/imagem.png'); ... }`

Comment: Pode ser também.

Answer (score 1):

Da para fazer só com `<hr>` **sim!**

Inclusive funciona até IE *(pelo menos no IE11 funciona)*

**Veja abaixo o exemplo.** A técnica usa a imagem como background da `<hr>` e com o `linear-gradient` eu fiz as linhas.

```css
hr { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    height:50px;
    border: none;
    background-image:url(http://placecage.com/50/50), 
    linear-gradient(to right, #666 0%,#666 45%, #fff 45%, #fff 55%, #666 55%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 50px 50px, 100% 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode estilizar um HR criando uma linha com CANVAS;

Se você não estiver usando nenhum framework como o BootStrap por exemplo, você terá que criar seu CSS na unha. Aí vai um exemplo;

```html
<style>
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
</style>

<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:100%; height:1px; background:blue; "></canvas></div>
<div class="divTableCell" align="center"><img src="http://www.lojaviena.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/8120.jpg" width="150"></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:100%; height:1px; background:blue; "></canvas></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```